# Ошибка при запуске aiogram бота с помошью проски url

Tags: python, aiogram, proxy

Прокси url мне нужен для деплоя бота на pythonanywhere, ввёл в баш консоль команду `echo $http_proxy`, добавил переменную с прокси адресом и вставил её в запуск бота, но выдало ошибку:

```
raise exceptions.NetworkError(f"aiohttp client throws an error: {e.__class__.__name__}: {e}")
aiogram.utils.exceptions.NetworkError: Aiohttp client throws an error: ClientConnectorError:
Cannot connect to host proxy.server:3128 ssl:default [getaddrinfo failed]
```

Код:

```
PROXY_URL = 'http://proxy.server:3128'

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN, proxy=PROXY_URL)
```

Comment: Ну ошибка говорит о том, что не получается подключиться, `http://proxy.server:3128` точно живой?